# how to check how long a program/application has been running or has run?

Tags: process, parental-controls

Is it possible to set a timer for a running application and save that data somewhere global?

I am doing some volunteer work in an internet cafe where kids are the main users and we would like to get them to do tux math for 10 minutes which they don't do because of the many distractions on the internet.

So I was wondering if getting the amount of time an application has been run is possible.

Comment: This won't work because they'll just open browser leaving Tux Math running in the background :)

Comment: yeah that's another thing, but what we might do is write a script on the startup of firefox to get the total time tux math has run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, maybe a different approach:
Create a user, that is allowed ONLY to use TuxMath. No Mozilla, no Totem, nothing, except TuxMath. After 10 minutes, You will change thieir priviliges to use other soft, or give them password to different user that is allowed to do other stuff.

Comment: yep, certainly possible. seems to be an easier approach but tux math won't be forced to them. but they don't have any options, so I guess they will just use it anyway

Answer (score 1):

Change the shortcut used by the kids to call a bash script, with the time command in it:

time /bin/yourprogram

Then do something with the output of time in the script, such as write the value to a text file or something.